# Type conflicts between projects

Tags: go

I want to move code used by a specific subdomain its own project, which will be imported by the main code base which is currently resides in.  I am able to import code from the subdomain into the main project successfully, until I add the Gorilla Mux code.  For example, this works:

```
// imports and non-relevant routes removed for simplicity
r := mux.NewRouter()
// Primary site routes here...
s := r.Host("subdomain-regex-here").Subrouter()
s.HandleFunc("/", people.Index)
http.ListenAndServe("localhost:8080", r)
```

But when I move the subdomain to its own project and import it, then call the LoadRoutes() function which passes in the mux.Router object from the primary site, I receive an error.  Here's the code:

```
// Primary Project
r := mux.NewRouter()
// Primary site routes here...

// function located in the subdomain go project, which is imported
func LoadRoutes(host string, r *m.Router) {

    s := r.Host(host).Subrouter()
    s.HandleFunc("/", people.Index)
    s.HandleFunc("/people", people.Index)
    s.HandleFunc("/person/new", people.New)
}
```

**# command-line-arguments
./main.go:25: cannot use r (type *"primary_site/vendor/github.com/gorilla/mux".Router) as type *"subdomain_site/vendor/github.com/gorilla/mux".Router in argument to routers.LoadRoutes**

It looks like I have two instances of the Gorilla Mux, from two separate projects, that are conflicting.  I only import packages from the subdomain site to the primary site, not the other way around.  This exact code works perfectly as long as I have it in a single project, but when I try to separate the projects, it breaks.

Since I pass in the instance of mux.NewRouter(), why am I having a conflict?

Comment: You should only have one top level vendor directory in your project for this reason

Comment: These are two separate groups of code - the main site is a project, the subdomain site is a package.

Comment: If they are both being imported into the same program, they are not separate as far as the build tools are concerned.

Comment: Only the subdomain project is being imported into the primary website project.  both main folders are located under src/ of my gopath, at the same level.

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 vendor directories in your project. You need to flatten them into a single vendor directory at the top level in order to share vendored types between packages. Remove the `subdomain_site/vendor` and only use the vendor directory in your main pacakage.

Comment: These are two separate projects. Src/proj1 and src/proj2. They are NOT the same project.

Comment: @dingalingchickenwiing You said you import the subdomain site into the primary site, that makes them part of the same program. Call it what you like, but multiple vendor directories in the same project will cause type mismatch errors like this.

Comment: I may have used the wrong terminology as I am new, but I tried to explain that both projects were the same folder level under $GOPATH/src. for example, $GOPATH/src/proj1 and $GOPATH/src/proj2. If what you said is true, then every project I ever build will actually be part of the same project and there will never be a distinction between any projects.

Comment: @dingalingchickenwiing, so you're saying that all code you ever intend to write will be imported into the same main program? If that's the case, then yes you will only have one project. Maybe think of it this way, don't put a vendor directory in "libraries" -- only put one in the package creating your final binary.